# How can I build a web template using css grid to be like this?

Tags: html, css

I want to build a web template like this image:

[web template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BrqLz.png)

It should be responsive and all items in main and footer sections need to be center aligned.

Code is below

```css
html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font: 1.6rem helvetica, Arial;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "header" "main" "footer";
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 5rem 1fr 5rem;
  height: 100%;
}

.header {
  grid-area: header;
  background-color: #203040;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}

.main {
  grid-area: main;
}

.footer {
  grid-area: footer;
  background-color: #203040;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header class="header">
    <div>
      <a class="brand-link" href="/">amazona</a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <a class="header-link" href="/signin">Sign in</a>
      <a class="header-link" href="/cart">Cart</a>
    </div>
  </header>
  <main class="main">
    Product List
  </main>
  <footer class="footer">
    All rights reserved.
  </footer>
</div>
```

but the content of main and footer are not center aligned.
How can I fix that?

Comment: then add a `text-align: center` declaration to their styles?

Comment: No. I want to make it center-aligned vertically and horizontally.

Comment: [ask] but [Is This On Topic?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @Rob What do you mean by putting 2 links instead of answering the question. I want to make staff center-aligned vertically and horizontally in a grid.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way i know is to have those two elements set to `display: flex` and setting the `justify-content` and `align-items` properties.

```css
html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font: 1.6rem helvetica, Arial;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "header" "main" "footer";
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 5rem 1fr 5rem;
  height: 100%;
}

.header {
  grid-area: header;
  background-color: #203040;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}

.main {
  grid-area: main;
}

.footer {
  grid-area: footer;
  background-color: #203040;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.main,
.footer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header class="header">
    <div>
      <a class="brand-link" href="/">amazona</a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <a class="header-link" href="/signin">Sign in</a>
      <a class="header-link" href="/cart">Cart</a>
    </div>
  </header>
  <main class="main">
    Product List
  </main>
  <footer class="footer">
    All rights reserved.
  </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: I want to make it center-aligned vertically and horizontally. Your solution is only for horizontally

Answer (score 0):

There is CSS element called `text-align`

**EDIT:** Also `margin: auto auto;` should center `.main` in the middle of the screen.

Add this:

```
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "header" "main" "footer";
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 5rem 1fr 5rem;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.footer {
  grid-area: footer;
  background-color: #203040;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
}
.main {
  grid-area: main;
  margin: auto auto;
}
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/yotking789/pen/GRgvvba)

Comment: I want to make it center-aligned vertically and horizontally. Your solution is only for horizontally